# Python selenium. How do I tell selenium to wait until a key is clickable?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

for example:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#yes')
# wait until it's done loading and then it'll be available to click again
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#yes')
```

this is the loading element when it's not loading. When it's loading display: block

```
<div id="loading" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: Have you read this? http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a method built into the selenium library to do just that:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, [TimeToWait]).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ElementName"))
```